# Implementation of Calendar in MVC 4.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, events, calendar, scheduled-tasks

I have an requirement to add calendar using "DayPilotLite"
in MVC.
 So, I have downloaded the demo and installed in my current mvc 4.0 app.
I am now having requirement to show "bubble" on Hover of any event.
So, I am trying to get it but I do not have much
information regarding daypilot lite. Even googled and find out some solution but neither of 
them are working.

```
I am referring to this link
http://mvc.daypilot.org/adding-event-bubble-to-daypilot-calendar/

but  this extension does not exists in there dll

<%=Html.DayPilotBubble("bubble", new DayPilotBubbleConfig{})%>
```

DayPilotbubble does not exists in it's HTMl Helper . Please help me . I am Very dissapointed .

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="DayPilot.Web.Mvc.Enums.Calendar" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="DayPilot.Web.Mvc.Events.Calendar" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    AJAX Drag&amp;Drop Event Calendar
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">



<script type="text/javascript">

    function createEvent(start, end, resource) {
        modal().showUrl("<%= ResolveUrl("~/Dialog/NewEvent") %>?start=" + start.toStringSortable() + "&end=" + end.toStringSortable());
    }

    function editEvent(id) {
        modal().showUrl("<%= ResolveUrl("~/Dialog/Edit/") %>" + id);
    }

    function modal() {
        var modal = new DayPilot.Modal();
        modal.top = 60;
        modal.width = 500;
        modal.opacity = 30;
        modal.border = "5px solid #d0d0d0";
        modal.closed = function () {
            if (this.result == "OK") {

                dpc.commandCallBack('refresh');
            }
            dpc.clearSelection();
        };

        modal.height = 600;
        return modal;
    }

       $("#divPrint").live("click", function (e) {
          window.print();
        });

</script>

<%--<div class="note"><b>Note:</b> This page uses the customizable <a href="http://code.daypilot.org/81367/daypilot-modal">DayPilot modal dialog</a> for event creating and editing.</div>--%>
<div style="padding-bottom:10px;cursor:pointer;" id="divPrint">Print</div>

<div>


        <%= Html.DayPilotCalendar("dpc", new DayPilotCalendarConfig { 
                BackendUrl = ResolveUrl("~/Calendar/Backend"),
                ViewType = DayPilot.Web.Mvc.Enums.Calendar.ViewType.Week,

                TimeRangeSelectedHandling = TimeRangeSelectedHandlingType.JavaScript,
                TimeRangeSelectedJavaScript = "createEvent(start, end)",
                EventMoveHandling = EventMoveHandlingType.CallBack,
                EventResizeHandling = EventResizeHandlingType.CallBack,
                EventClickHandling = EventClickHandlingType.JavaScript,
                EventClickJavaScript = "editEvent(e.value());",             
                LoadingLabelText="<img src='" + ResolveUrl("~/Media/linked/ajax-loader-round.gif") + "' />",
                LoadingLabelBackColor="",
        })%>
</div>

</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Did you add the reference to library you intend to use?

Comment: yes Sir. "DayPilot.web.mvc.dll"

Comment: My "DayPilotExtensions" Class only contains "DayPilotMonth" and "DayPilotCalendar". I added a new method named as "DayPilotBubble" but that's not working at all.

Comment: Check if you have @using /*path to your html helper extensions*/? Could you show your HtmlHelper extension?

Comment: yes. Why not? Just a minute

Comment: Please check the updated questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add

```
<add namespace="DayPilot.Web.Mvc" />
```

into your `Views/Web.confing` file. You need to add it in section `configuration->system.web.webPages.razor->pages->namespaces`
The your namespaces section should look like this:

```
<namespaces>
   <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
   <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
   <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
   <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
   <add namespace="DayPilot.Web.Mvc" />
</namespaces>
```

It will add reference to `DayPilot.Web.Mvc` namespace globaly to all your views.
You also have an option to add `<%@ Import Namespace="DayPilot.Web.Mvc" %>` to every view where you use appropriate helper extensions.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, DayPilotLite doesn't have Bubble support. It's only in the Pro version of MVC.